# How can I add cookie from request header to a new site in opened web browser running with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

i had the cookie from the request header of a tiktok website account and i want to add it to a new page opened with selenium python to login to that account

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHFIJ.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--app=https://www.tiktok.com/")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        
driver.quit()
```

here is my script, i don't know what to do next :3

Thanks for taking the time to read this post, and I appreciate you for answering my question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cookies one by one. Here's an example of how you may achieve this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--app=https://www.tiktok.com/")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

cookies = [
    {'name': 'cookie_name_1', 'value': 'cookie_value_1', 'domain': 'cookie_domain_1'},
    {'name': 'cookie_name_2', 'value': 'cookie_value_2', 'domain': 'cookie_domain_2'},
    ...
]

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
     
driver.quit()
```